# Aautomatically Opening wrong Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to open `sucessfullyadd` activity from `luckyactivity` activity and I am using the `startActivity` method. However, it opens `homeactivity` and  after some time it opens a new `sucessfullyadd` activity. When I close my application `luckyactivity` is running on background. I try so many code but unable to solve the Problem. I posted my android Manifest and `Luckyactivity` code upper

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reward.ugifts">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> <!-- optional -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GoogleSigninActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChoiceSelection"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name=".LuckyWheel" />
        <activity
            android:name=".wallet"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".dialog.spinadd"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".dialog.inputrefersuccess"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".dialog.videosucess"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".dialog.sucessfullyadd">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Redeem"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".History"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Invite"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChoiceSelection">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ChoiceSelection" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Inputcode" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" /> <!-- POLLFISH -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.startapp.sdk.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="202685310" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.startapp.sdk.RETURN_ADS_ENABLED"
            android:value="false" /> <!-- Publisher SDK Specific -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification" />
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

```java
     // TIME INTERVAL
                                loadingDialog.show();
                                final int intervalTime = 3000;
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                        Intent openadd= new Intent(LuckyWheel.this, sucessfullyadd.class);
                                        openadd.putExtra("wonamount",  index * 1);
                                        startActivity(openadd);
                                    }

                                }, intervalTime);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) I went through your question, and moved the question to the begging, added code highlights and went through a bit of the punctuation. Hopefully that will help you getting a good answer. You might want to read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make it easier for you to get good answers. Good luck and once again welcome :)

Comment: You seem to be using some non-standard naming convention, which makes your code a bit confusing to read for other Java programmers. It would be a good idea to get into the habit of using standard naming. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java  When writing Android code it's also common for all Activity classes to have an "Activity" suffix in their name.